# how to make div act as a input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I set up a check boxes that will display a progress bar and show its current progress by its percentage. how do I make the div tag act as an input to save the value into the database

I tried using it on the div and it display the percentage but when I tried it using an input it fails to show the percentage

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-bar"></div>
  <div class="progressbar-label"></div>
  <input type="" name="" id="percentage">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // get box count
  var count = 0;
  var checked = 0;

  function countBoxes() {
    count = $("input[type='checkbox']").length;
    console.log(count);
  }

  countBoxes();
  $(":checkbox").click(countBoxes);

  // count checks

  function countChecked() {
    checked = $("input:checked").length;

    var percentage = parseInt(((checked / count) * 100), 10);
    $(".progressbar-bar").progressbar({
      value: percentage
    });
    $(".progressbar-label").text(percentage + "%");
    $('#percentage').text(percentage + "%")
  }

  countChecked();
  $(":checkbox").click(countChecked);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `contenteditable` attribute and then get the value by `innerHTML`.